# can you share photo to your application from photo library in ios

Tags: iphone, ios6, file-sharing

Hello everyone I am new in the iPhone and iPad development. I have heard that in `ios 6` there is one feature that allow user to share the photo from library to particular `iOS Applications`.
Like as we open the photo in photo library and push button for sharing we found there icons of `Facebook,twitter` and many more standard option.Can we put our app icon there to share photo to our app ?

Waiting for response.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't think it is easy to do but it not impossible.To achieve this you have to do some changes in SocialFramework.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try on it.If you can provide any link or sample code then it will be more helpful.